# AngularJS - What is the advantage of using $injector in this case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, interceptor

I was reading the following article: [Techniques for authentication in AngularJS applications](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec) when I saw this implementation:

```
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push([
    '$injector',
    function ($injector) {
      return $injector.get('AuthInterceptor');
    }
  ]);
})
.factory('AuthInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q,
                                      AUTH_EVENTS) {
  return {
    responseError: function (response) { 
      $rootScope.$broadcast({
        401: AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated,
        403: AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthorized,
        419: AUTH_EVENTS.sessionTimeout,
        440: AUTH_EVENTS.sessionTimeout
      }[response.status], response);
      return $q.reject(response);
    }
  };
})
```

Could someone please explain me why does the author use an injector here instead of:

```
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push({
    responseError: function (response) { 
      $rootScope.$broadcast({
        401: AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated,
        403: AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthorized,
        419: AUTH_EVENTS.sessionTimeout,
        440: AUTH_EVENTS.sessionTimeout
      }[response.status], response);
      return $q.reject(response);
    });
})
```

I would also appreciate if someone could explain to me why does he writes this:

```
'$injector',
```

before the function.

Thanks you all very much!

Comment: it creates a reusable component.

Comment: But where would I reuse that? It is quite specific? Right?